# Asynchronous versions of Google APIs?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-docs-api

Is there any way to queue up document list API requests and handle them asynchronously (similar to the google app engine async urlfetch requests)?

I could conceivably copy/rewrite a lot of the client request modification logic in DocsClient around a urlfetch request, but I'd rather avoid that if there's some other method already available.

The target environment is google app engine, and I'm aware of the async datastore APIs.

**EDIT**

I've now implemented basic functionality on `DocsClient.request` to accept a `callback` kwarg, so any higher-level client request will use async urlfetch and call the callback function with the result of the call.

Comment: What platform are you actually targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Documents List API library for Python (The GData Library) is rigidly synchronous. One solution would be to serialize the requests as tasks for a task queue and run them later, but the library itself won't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Serializing requests doesn't help with resource usage on GAE.  90% of the time of these requests is spent in I/O wait, which means the instance hours are almost wholly wasted.  Using async urlfetch allows the app to make use of that otherwise dead wait time.

Answer (score 5):

To write asynchronous code with google-docs-api and with any google api generally use [aiogoogle](https://pypi.org/project/aiogoogle/). For google-docs [this](https://aiogoogle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#discovery-docs-and-the-aiogoogle-object-explained) documentation will be helpful too.

Comment: and eight months